# How to properly use url in Ajax call in an MVC C# project using separate Javascript file

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, model-view-controller

In my project i have a button that saves the changed content of an html page.

The button looks like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-light" title="Export (Ctrl + E)" id="save-btn" data-hmi-action="saveAjax"  data-hmi-shortcut="ctrl+e">
     <i class="la la-save"></i>
</button>
```

The saveAjax in an external file is in a couple of parts.

```
saveAjax: function(fileName, startTemplateUrl, callback)
{
    var data = {};
    data["fileName"] = (fileName && fileName != "") ? fileName : HMI.FileManager.getCurrentUrl();
    data["startTemplateUrl"] = startTemplateUrl;
    if (!startTemplateUrl || startTemplateUrl == null)
    {
        data["html"] = this.getHtml();
    }
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Home/Save', //set your server side save script url
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            if (callback) callback(data);

        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.responseText);
        }
    });                 
}
```

The url above is my Controller Action. When executed it gives a Error 500 on the url in the console. I have a break set in the controller and as would be expected it bypasses that.

The second part is below:

```
saveAjax : function () {

    var url = Hmi.FileManager.getCurrentUrl();

    return Hmi.Builder.saveAjax(url, null, function (data) {
        $('#message-modal').modal().find(".modal-body").html("File saved at: " + data);
    });     
}
```

I have tried using a url on the razor page in the button, but since this already makes a call to the page for saveAjax and it is not a Id based call this will not work. The url in the console is the correct url, meaning it is going to the proper location. I think it is looking for a page called Save rather than going to the ActionResult. In this case i do not need a view for this.

I am looking to see if i am correct about it looking for a page and not the ActionResult and if so is there a way i can get this to look at the ActionResult instead of a page.

Maybe a way to pass something to the javascript file that gets the url and then use that in the saveAjax script.

To add to this below is the data-hmi-action which is used on all the buttons in the project.

```
init: function() {
    $("[data-hmi-action]").each(function () {
        on = "click";
        if (this.dataset.hmiOn) on = this.dataset.hmiOn;

        $(this).on(on, HMI.Gui[this.dataset.hmiAction]);
        if (this.dataset.hmiShortcut)
        {
            $(document).bind('keydown', this.dataset.hmiShortcut, HMI.Gui[this.dataset.hmiAction]);
            $(window.FrameDocument, window.FrameWindow).bind('keydown', this.dataset.hmiShortcut, HMI.Gui[this.dataset.hmiAction]);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Edit---

In this particular case i was experiencing a 500 server error because i was trying to capture HTML / Javascript that is on a page. Dot Net scans that information for fictitious characters. Code markup looks as though someone has passed information along with what you are trying to send as a threat.

It can be disabled. In my case it was adding

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

to the controller action. You can also cover the whole application by using in the web.config file.

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

There are other ways to do this in different apps this example is for MVC only. 
You can check out the address below for more details on other apps.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh882339(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: What kind of `500` error is it?  Does it give you a stack trace? Can you set a breakpoint in the controller and step through?

Comment: That is part of the issue. it doesn't even hit the controller. I have a break point in the controller. I am reading the 500 error from the console window. Since it is not going to an actual page it doesn't give me a stack trace.  The console has this:  jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:50097/Home/Save 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2
saveAjax @ builder.js:1336
saveAjax @ builder.js:1456
dispatch @ jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2

Comment: --- When i click the link to jquery it just says code was not executed because server returned 500 Error..

Comment: Check the `Output` window inside VS, it should spit out at least a partial stack trace.  Can you add your controller code please.

Comment: So i captured the error in the console. was able to look at it. Apparently .net has an issue with saving html markup code. It thinks it is fictitious or someone is trying to hack you. There is a way around it. I have to put something in the page to allow it. I think i have run into this before because it sounds familiar. I will post my findings and update the question as soon as i read the documentation..